# Populate excel cell with date every 2 weeks

Tags: excel, vba

I need to populate a cell every two weeks with a date.

We work with Agile - Scrum and I want two cells (Start and End date) to be added via a function of via VBA, that is the sprint duration.

[image]

Currently we add it manually and I dont want the team members to add it each sprint.

To make my question clear: I dont want to do a manual input every sprint rather I want the dates to be populated automatically?

Comment: What is your problem? Show us what you have already done, and where are you having problems. Also you may want to learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: @drec4s its clear: Currently we add it manually not sure how I can make that more clear? and the problem is that I need it to be automatically added, also stated clearly in question..

Comment: So the next week date would be 23rd to 4th of May ??

Comment: Use a table with two fields, header in line 1. Start: =startofproject+(ROW()-2)*14 End: =[Start]+11

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following under a button click or even under the Workbook_Open event to add two weeks to the cell values, in my case, I've used B1 for Sprint Start and B2 for Sprint End:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(1, 2).Value + 14
    'Add 14 days to cell B1
    ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = ws.Cells(2, 2).Value + 14
    'Add 14 days to cell B2
End Sub
```